# sorting element of one array into two other arrays by a specific element

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

hi i've got an array i made from a txt file. each element of the array is something like this:

```
examplea   A   10.20.5.197
exampleb   A   10.10.7.178
examplec   A   10.20.75.116
exampled   A   10.20.90.170
```

i wanna loop through the original array to find all the ip addresses that are "/10.20.\d+.\d+/" and store them in another array (wifiArray) and store the rest in another(localArray).
here's what i got so far:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var lineArray = 
fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/intern3/zonerecords.txt').toString().split("\n");
var IP = /10.20\d+.\d+/;

var wifiArray = new Array();
var localArray = new Array();

function ArraySplit(string, Originalarray, Array1, Array2) {
var ind = 0;
for( var i=0; i < Originalarray.length; i++) {

    if(String(string).match(Originalarray[i])) {
    Array1[ind++] = Originalarray[i];
}
    else {
        Array2[ind++] = Originalarray[i];
    }
}
}

ArraySplit(IP, lineArray, wifiArray, localArray);

fs.writeFile('C:/Users/intern3/test2.txt', wifiArray, function(err) {
if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
}

console.log("The file was saved!");
});

fs.writeFile('C:/Users/intern3/test3.txt', localArray, function(err) {
if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
}

console.log("The file was saved!");


});

fs.writeFile('C:/Users/intern3/test.txt', lineArray, function(err) {
if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
}

console.log("The file was saved!");


});
```

if i run this test2.txt just prints a wall of ,,,,,,,,,,,,
and test3.txt prints the original array.
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found your problem. You are naming (And using!) your variables incorrectly; And you have incorrect pattern. Try `var IP = /10\.20\.\d+\.\d+/;`
You have:

```
function ArraySplit(string, Originalarray, Array1, Array2) {
   // ...

   // This is WRONG, as string is a PATTERN to be matched
   //if(String(string).match(Originalarray[i])) {
   // Now it is correct more or less
   if(String(Originalarray[i]).match(string)) {
      // ...
   }
}
```

always use verbose names. It costs you nothing to have `ipPatternMatcher` vs `pattern` or even `string`

For the problem for topic, you can use reducer

```
const orig = [{
    a: "examplea",
    b: "A",
    ip: "10.20.5.197"
  },
  {
    a: "exampleb",
    b: "A",
    ip: "10.10.7.178"
  },
  {
    a: "examplec",
    b: "A",
    ip: "10.20.75.116"
  },
  {
    a: "exampled",
    b: "A",
    ip: "10.20.90.170"
  }
]

var IPPattern = /^10\.20\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/;

const accumulator = {wifiAddresses: [], localAddresses: []};

const reducer = (accumulator, value) => {
  if (value.ip.match(IPPattern)) {
    accumulator.wifiAddresses.push(value);
  } else {
    accumulator.localAddresses.push(value);
  }
  return accumulator;
}

console.log(orig.reduce(reducer, accumulator))
```

I'll try to find where you have a problem, but it seems like you have error with regexp and unescaping dot

Comment: yes! my regexp pattern was wrong, that was silly of me. thanks for the advice.

Comment: Ok i had a chance to look through your solution and it does exactly what i want it to do but the trouble is my txt file has thousands of data, so i can't really write them all in the array individually like that. is there something i can do to make the txt file into json something?

Comment: You already have it as an array `var lineArray = 
fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/intern3/zonerecords.txt').toString().split("\n");`. All you have to do before calling the reduce function is to map these lines into an object, like so: 

      `fileArray.map(line => {
         var temp = line.split("\\s+");
         return {label:temp[0], type:temp[1], ip:temp[2]};
      }).reduce(...`

Comment: ok cool that split the lines into objects. but now i get a "cannot read property 'match' of undefined"

Comment: if (value.ip.match(IPPattern))

Comment: And this is a great moment to debug my code!  :) I'm mapping file array instead of line array, should be 'lineArray.map' :)

Comment: yeah haha i caught onto that. it's still giving same error. i'm sorry i'm fairly new to coding!